# Fit recaptcha inside the module

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, module-style

I am using Joomla ReCaptcha on my custom module using the below code.  The capthca comes and it works great but it looks very ugly.... :-(

**PHP**

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_1');
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Any suggestions to make it neat and fit?

Comment: A link to the website (if available online) might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set recaptcha element width with css like that:

Place those lines in your module's php file

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$recaptcha = '#dynamic_recaptcha_1>div>div {'
    .'width: 100% !important;'
    .'border-radius: 4px;'
    .'overflow: hidden;'
    .'max-width: 300px;'
    .'}';
$document->addStyleDeclaration($recaptcha);
```

But this style has only 1 problem, it makes the recaptcha logo invisble.

[image]